# HBase (Hortonworks) access denied exception

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hortonworks-data-platform, apache-ranger, knox-gateway

We are using HBase as our choice of storage in a Hortonworks environment.
We have one node running and are planning to upgrade to multiple nodes if everything works fine. Currently, we use Knox SSO to sign in to the services.

To access the data within HBase we use the WebHBase api.
Signing in through Knox SSO works just fine. The user we use to do this ("testuser") has full access rights on Hbase, configured in Ranger.

However, something goes wrong when we are through Knox and arrived at Hbase. No we get the exception that user "root". How come that it asks for user "root" while we want to fetch data with "testuser"? Obviously we can make a user "root" and give it full clearance, but this is highly undesirable. We think there must be some mistake with the user authorization within Ranger/Knox regarding the services.

Here is the stacktrace we get when accessing the webhbase API through our Knox gateway:

> Forbidden org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.AccessDeniedException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.AccessDeniedException: Insufficient
>   permissions for user ‘root',action: scannerOpen, tableName:testtable,
>   family:r.     at
>   org.apache.ranger.authorization.hbase.RangerAuthorizationCoprocessor.authorizeAccess(RangerAuthorizationCoprocessor.java:511)
>     at
>   org.apache.ranger.authorization.hbase.RangerAuthorizationCoprocessor.preScannerOpen(RangerAuthorizationCoprocessor.java:901)
>     at
>   org.apache.ranger.authorization.hbase.RangerAuthorizationCoprocessor.preScannerOpen(RangerAuthorizationCoprocessor.java:856)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RegionCoprocessorHost$50.call(RegionCoprocessorHost.java:1267)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RegionCoprocessorHost$RegionOperation.call(RegionCoprocessorHost.java:1638)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RegionCoprocessorHost.execOperation(RegionCoprocessorHost.java:1712)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RegionCoprocessorHost.execOperationWithResult(RegionCoprocessorHost.java:1687)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RegionCoprocessorHost.preScannerOpen(RegionCoprocessorHost.java:1262)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.scan(RSRpcServices.java:2279)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:32295)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2127)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor.consumerLoop(RpcExecutor.java:133)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$1.run(RpcExecutor.java:108)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.instantiateException(RemoteException.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException.unwrapRemoteException(RemoteException.java:95)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.ProtobufUtil.getRemoteException(ProtobufUtil.java:333)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.openScanner(ScannerCallable.java:387)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.call(ScannerCallable.java:201)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.call(ScannerCallable.java:63)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithoutRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:200)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas$RetryingRPC.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:364)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallableWithReplicas$RetryingRPC.call(ScannerCallableWithReplicas.java:338)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RpcRetryingCaller.callWithRetries(RpcRetryingCaller.java:126)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ResultBoundedCompletionService$QueueingFuture.run(ResultBoundedCompletionService.java:65)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)    Caused by:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RemoteWithExtrasException(org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.AccessDeniedException):
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.AccessDeniedException: Insufficient
>   permissions for user ‘root',action: scannerOpen, tableName:rowphyste,
>   family:r.     at
>   org.apache.ranger.authorization.hbase.RangerAuthorizationCoprocessor.authorizeAccess(RangerAuthorizationCoprocessor.java:511)
>     at
>   org.apache.ranger.authorization.hbase.RangerAuthorizationCoprocessor.preScannerOpen(RangerAuthorizationCoprocessor.java:901)
>     at
>   org.apache.ranger.authorization.hbase.RangerAuthorizationCoprocessor.preScannerOpen(RangerAuthorizationCoprocessor.java:856)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RegionCoprocessorHost$50.call(RegionCoprocessorHost.java:1267)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RegionCoprocessorHost$RegionOperation.call(RegionCoprocessorHost.java:1638)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RegionCoprocessorHost.execOperation(RegionCoprocessorHost.java:1712)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RegionCoprocessorHost.execOperationWithResult(RegionCoprocessorHost.java:1687)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RegionCoprocessorHost.preScannerOpen(RegionCoprocessorHost.java:1262)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.RSRpcServices.scan(RSRpcServices.java:2279)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientProtos.java:32295)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:2127)
>     at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:107)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor.consumerLoop(RpcExecutor.java:133)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$1.run(RpcExecutor.java:108)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl.call(RpcClientImpl.java:1225)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:213)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.AbstractRpcClient$BlockingRpcChannelImplementation.callBlockingMethod(AbstractRpcClient.java:287)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.protobuf.generated.ClientProtos$ClientService$BlockingStub.scan(ClientProtos.java:32741)
>     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ScannerCallable.openScanner(ScannerCallable.java:379)
>     ... 10 more

We are currently not doing user mapping (i.e. principal mapping) in Knox topologies. My gateway-audit.log looks like this:

> 17/05/05 11:58:33
>   ||aac40856-3c3f-46a5-8b90-970d54bc0a21|audit|WEBHBASE||||access|uri|/gateway/default/hbase/testdatabase/*|unavailable|Request
>   method: GET 17/05/05 11:58:33
>   ||aac40856-3c3f-46a5-8b90-970d54bc0a21|audit|WEBHBASE||||access|uri|/gateway/default/hbase/testdatabase/*|success|Response
>   status: 302 17/05/05 11:58:33
>   ||5737b75b-9082-44e5-9afd-9675e9c36c43|audit|KNOXSSO||||access|uri|/gateway/knoxsso/api/v1/websso?originalUrl=mydomain/gateway/default/hbase/testdatabase/%2A|unavailable|Request
>   method: GET 17/05/05 11:58:33
>   ||5737b75b-9082-44e5-9afd-9675e9c36c43|audit|KNOXSSO|testuser|||authentication|uri|/gateway/knoxsso/api/v1/websso?originalUrl=mydomain/gateway/default/hbase/testdatabase/%2A|success|
>   17/05/05 11:58:33
>   ||5737b75b-9082-44e5-9afd-9675e9c36c43|audit|KNOXSSO|testuser|||authentication|uri|/gateway/knoxsso/api/v1/websso?originalUrl=mydomain/gateway/default/hbase/testdatabase/%2A|success|Groups:
>   [] 17/05/05 11:58:33
>   ||5737b75b-9082-44e5-9afd-9675e9c36c43|audit|KNOXSSO|testuser|||access|uri|/gateway/knoxsso/api/v1/websso?originalUrl=mydomain/gateway/default/hbase/testdatabase/%2A|success|Response
>   status: 303 17/05/05 11:58:33
>   ||53594522-40b6-4040-ad2e-07e71a8ae112|audit|WEBHBASE||||access|uri|/gateway/default/hbase/testdatabase/*|unavailable|Request
>   method: GET 17/05/05 11:58:33
>   ||53594522-40b6-4040-ad2e-07e71a8ae112|audit|WEBHBASE||||dispatch|uri|mydomain:60080/testdatabase/*?user.name=testuser|unavailable|Request
>   method: GET 17/05/05 11:58:33
>   ||53594522-40b6-4040-ad2e-07e71a8ae112|audit|WEBHBASE||||dispatch|uri|mydomain:60080/testdatabase/*?user.name=testuser|success|Response
>   status: 403 17/05/05 11:58:33
>   ||53594522-40b6-4040-ad2e-07e71a8ae112|audit|WEBHBASE||||access|uri|/gateway/default/hbase/testdatabase/*|success|Response
>   status: 403

Comment: This looks weird, can you look at the gateway-audit.log, there you can see details about the user Knox is seeing. Also, are you doing user mapping in knox topology ?

Comment: We are not doing user mapping currently. I update my post to contain gateway-audit.log. Would you suggest us to add principal mapping?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the additional info, it appears to me, looking at the audit-log that Knox is seeing the 'testuser'

```
9675e9c36c43|audit|KNOXSSO|testuser|||authentication|uri|/gateway/knoxsso/api/v1/websso?originalUrl=mydomain/gateway/default/hbase/testdatabase/%2A|success|Groups: [] 17/05/05 11:58:33 ||5737b75b-9082-44e5-9afd-

4040-ad2e-07e71a8ae112|audit|WEBHBASE||||dispatch|uri|mydomain:60080/testdatabase/?user.name=testuser|success|Response status: 403 17/05/05 11:58:33 ||53594522-40b6-4040-ad2e-
```

You might want to check hbase-site.xml file for related settings. This is a [link to Knox documentation](https://knox.apache.org/books/knox-0-12-0/user-guide.html#HBase+Examples) that talks about the settings.

Comment: I uploaded my settings here: https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/100385/webhbase-access-denied-exception.html

I cannot detect any mistakes yet.